# Reset hidesBarsOnSwipe in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

Where and how do I have to reset `hidesBarsOnSwipe`? I set the option in a View Controller which I push and want to reset it for the View Controller which did the push. What I tried until now is setting `hidesBarsOnSwipe` to `false` in the `viewDidDisappear` and in the `viewDidLoad` of the pushing ViewController.

The Navigationbar is still disappearing.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (!visiblePOIs.isEmpty) {
        let beaconInfo = visiblePOIs[indexPath.item]
        var controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailController")! as! DetailController
        controller.setup(beaconInfo)
        self.parentViewController!.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

DetailController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

next view controller write in viewDidload

```
First Vc

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}

Second VC
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
 super.viewWillAppear(animated)
 self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
 self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:   true)
 }
```

I hope its works

Comment: instead of navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true check it  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true) its work or not

Comment: But that's not what I want. If it's completely hidden I cannot use the navigation with back any more.

Answer (score 1):

I had your exact problem. Here's how I solved it. (You can adapt this based on your needs.)

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {            
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //Correct the nav bar state unwinding from segues
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }

    override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)

        //Toggle the auto-hiding nav bar when this view gets added/removed from the nav controller
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = !self.navigationController!.hidesBarsOnSwipe
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

        //Reset the nav bar to visible when segueing to another view
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to limit the functionality of the auto-hiding feature to the desired view controller without adding code to all associated view controllers.