# Nav Bar not hiding

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

For some reason, my bottom nav bar is not hiding on my main view controller (blue screen in the following storyboard):

[image: Main Storyboard]

I do not want a tab bar to display on the bottom of the blue screen, so I've put in the following code in its view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

It top navigation bar is not displaying (as expected), but the bottom bar is not hiding. It's also displaying twice on every screen thereafter (see screenshot below):

[image: App Screen]

Is it because I have a Tab Bar Controller in my interface builder? Is there a way to implement the tab bar controller with four icons programmatically instead?  The only screen that I really want the tab bar controller to be on is the Table View.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325292/reset-hidesbarsonswipe-in-swift/30325619#30325619

Comment: @Memon, thanks.  I tried this, and unfortunately, the tab bar still displays on the bottom of the blue screen.  Also, when I swipe to the green screen, the bottom tab bar displays for one second and then disappears.  I'm wondering if this has to do with the fact that I've placed a Tab Bar Controller at the beginning of my flow.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`

In the view controller with blue background color:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let desVC: UIViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
        desVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zy.liu, I tried putting the following in viewWillAppear of the blue screen (ViewController.swift),  'self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true'
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self, animated: true), and it gave me an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported'

Comment: I added that as you suggested.  The bottom bar still appears on the blue screen, and when it segues to the next screen (the green one), two bottom bars appear initially (same problem shown in the screenshot provided above), and then after one second, the upper one disappears. Any other ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: animated)` and `TextField` top connection(Safe Area) change `Superview`.